# R equivalent of SAS OBS= option

Tags: r, system

SAS has OBS= option to limit the number of observation to read. Once put as system options, it can be applied on all the dataset that to be read by the program. It become useful to test the program before running on large full dataset.

Wondering if there is similar option/function in R? Or we have to specify number of observations for each input data frame in R?

Comment: Why not just specify an `OBS` at the start of your script and refer to that whenever you read in a file?

Comment: You can use the  **nrows** argument inside the **read.table** function

Comment: Thanks. If my input data is written by save() function. When I use load() function to read in, is there a way to just read in limited number of observation?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the comments into an answer, at the top of your script you can define

```
OBS = 100 # however many rows you want to start
```

When reading in data with `read.csv`, `read.table`, etc.,

```
... = read.table(..., nrows = OBS)
```

As described in `?read.table`, if you set `nrows` (hence `OBS`) to a negative number (such as the default, `-1`), it will be ignored.

Comment: It might be convenient to create a temporary-use function that hard-codes the value, but yea, this is what I had in mind (+1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have less then 100 rows you can use:

```
head(my_dataframe,100)
```

If you have a dataframe with at least 100 variables, will error on you otherwise:

```
my_dataframe[1:100,]
```

Answer (score 0):

be aware that 'obs' is a short form for lastobs,
the companion option is firstobs

e.g. read rows 1--5: (firstobs=1)

```
set sashelp.class(obs=5);
```

e.g. read rows 5--10:

```
set sashelp.class(firstobs=5,obs=10);
```